# How to Capture 3 images and display in 3 diff imageview

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I have 3 Imageview.I just want to capture 3 images and display in 3 imageview respectively in android.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        this.imageView1 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        this.imageView2 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button photoButton1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button photoButton2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

}

this is my code but i cant set image on three diff image view
my idea is to on three button open camra and display image on respective image view

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: Its so simple userequest code as a differentiation value. You can check in onActivityResult that from which request code activity is started which will also tell about button click. check in onActivityResult this request code and add images on their respective image view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different request code for each of the images:

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
        }
    });
photoButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
        }
    });
```

In Activity result set to different image view depending upon the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks another question is that how to show  image size below the image in text view

Comment: File f = new File(filepath);
                        long fileSizeInBytes = f.length();
                        long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
                        long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;